# Is JavaScript Array.map generally an endofunctor or just a functor?

Tags: javascript, functor, map-function

1. A functor is a structure-preserving transformation between categories. It's some way to map objects from one category to objects of another category while also preserving the arrows between objects—think of it as a category homomorphism.
2. An endofunctor is a functor from one category back to the same category.

In JavaScript, Array.map can be generally chained because it always returns Array.

```
someArray
.map(f1) 
.map(f2) 
.map(f3)
...
```

So, at the first time, considering (2), I simply thought "ok, since Array is a special type that has a method map, and it returns the same type, JavaScript array must be endofunctor."

However, considering (1), I thought "wait, is it just a structure saving feature of all functors that is not limited to endofunctor?"

In other words, is it safe to say "if it is chainable, it is an endofunctor"? Or it's invalid since chainable map and endo- is another concept?

Comment: Note that everything chainable is not necessarily returning the same type as was input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Array.map is endofunctor in javascript, as it returns object by using object as self. Notice, only in JS, as it use simply `object`.

In other lang like C#, when you define an array you need to give type of containning, mapping between them become functor but not endofunctor.

It is easy to identify. If and only if a functor of class always return the same class as itself, this functor is an endofunctor.

Thus in a class `MyClass`,

```
a: function(){
   return this;
},
b: function(){
   return new MyClass();
}
```

Those are endofunctor.

However, it is not safe to say a chain-able functor is endofunctor.

Simply imagine two class, `class MyClassA()` and `class MyClassB()`, both have a functor sharing same name (this is usual).

In `MyClassA`,

```
changetype: function(){
   return MyClassB;
}
```

and vice versa.

So, once you can write something like

```
a = new MyClassA();
a.changetype().changetype().changetype()......
```

and have no trouble.

So if you find a functor chain-able, you cannot determine if it is an endofunctor.As sharing same name functor is very very typical in all programming language.

Comment: Excellent answer with further detail than I imagined. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's a functor (more or less), not an endofunctor.

First thing to realize is that a functor in mathematics is not the same as a functor in programming, in the same way that a class from mathematical set theory is not the same as a class in programming. In programming -- specifically in Haskell -- Functor is the name of an interface. Yes, an interface. Because in Haskell, a typeclass defines an interface, and Functor is the name of a typeclass that requires types implement a function named "fmap" in order to satisfy the Functor interface.

More details here: https://motts42.blogspot.com/2017/12/functors-according-to-haskell.html

The Functor typeclass looks like this, `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. The names "f", "a", and "b" are all variable *types*. So, for example, fmap might convert a `Box Int` to a `Box String`, or a `List String` to a `List Bool`. The container type, such as Box or List, will *always* be the same, as represented in fmap's signature by the type variable "f". The only part that can change is the type contained by the container.

Haskell doesn't define a thing called endofunctor, so now we have to speculate a little bit. After all, remember that a Haskell functor is an interface on types, not a transformation between categories. In mathematics, an endofunctor is a functor that maps a category to itself. The best way I can interpret that in the context of Haskell's Functor is a functor where fmap's type variables "a" and "b" are the same type. That is, an fmap function that maps a `Box Int` to another `Box Int`, or a `List String` to another `List String`.

In the case of JavaScript's array, sure, you could map an array of numbers to another array of numbers, but you're by no means limited to doing that. You're free to map an array of anything to an array of literally anything else.

Comment: I think it's very misleading that people frequently mention "A in mathematics is not the same as a A in programming" I don't like it including Wikipedia says A(Mathematics)/A(Programming). Programming is Mathematics, and especially, Haskell or functional programming. Having said that, JavaScript Array is not list but tuple. We don't give a type to an Array as `Array Int` or `Array Strings` like Haskell lists. It's just Array or just Object. Therefore I believe your answer is not correct. Thanks.